# Expected flips for $n$ coins

Tags: probability

> In the start, $n$ coins are flipped. Every round, if a coin lands
>   heads, it stops being flipped. What is the expected number of rounds it will
>   take to stop flipping completely?

For $1$ coin, the answer is $2$. For $n$ coins, this is $E(1) + 2E(2) + ...$, with each $E(X)$ meaning one coin took $X$ tries and all the others took $\le X$ tries ($\max = X$). I am unsure of how to find a formula for this.

Comment: Another way to look at this is "about how many coins stop per round?" If you think of it that way, you might find a pretty swift answer.

Comment: @TerraHyde For $3$ coins, the possibilities would be $(3), (2,1), (1,2), (1, 1,1)$. Is this a partitioning problem?

Comment: How likely is it that a coin (assuming it is fair) comes up heads? About 50% probability, yes? So what percentage of coins can you expect to come up heads on any given flip?

You could look at it as a partitioning problem, but it will require more work than it is worth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be the number of times we need to flip the $i$-th coin and $X$ the total number of rounds.

Then, $X = \displaystyle\max_{1 \le i \le n} X_i$. So, we have:

$\Pr[X \ge m]$ $= 1-\Pr[X < m]$

$= 1-\Pr[X_i < m \ \text{for all} \ i]$

$= 1-\Pr[X_i < m]^n$

$= 1-(1-\Pr[X_i \ge m])^n$

$= 1-(1-\Pr[m-1 \ \text{heads in a row}])^n$

$= ?$ (I'll let you finish this)

Finally, use the formula $E[X] = \displaystyle\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}m\Pr[X = m] = \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\Pr[X \ge m]$.

EDIT: The values of $E[X]$ for $n = 1,2,3,4,5,6$ are $2, \dfrac{8}{3}, \dfrac{22}{7}, \dfrac{368}{105}, \dfrac{2470}{651}, \dfrac{7880}{1953}$.

The sequence of numerators and denominators are [OEIS A158466](https://oeis.org/A158466) and [OEIS A158467](https://oeis.org/A158467) respectively.

Answer (score 5):

The probability that a given coin hasn't stopped after $k$ rounds is $(1/2)^k$, so the probability that it's stopped is $1-(1/2)^k$, so the probability that they've all stopped is $\left(1-(1/2)^k\right)^n$, so the probability that they haven't all stopped is $1-\left(1-(1/2)^k\right)^n$. Then the expected number of rounds is

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(1-\left(1-\left(\frac12\right)^k\right)^n\right)&=&-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^n\binom nj(-1)^j\left(\frac12\right)^{jk}\\
&=&
-\sum_{j=1}^n\binom nj(-1)^j\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac12\right)^{jk}\\
&=&
-\sum_{j=1}^n\binom nj\frac{(-1)^j}{1-\left(\frac12\right)^j}\;.
\end{eqnarray}

The first few values are $2$ for $n=1$, then $2\cdot2-4/3=2\frac23$ for $n=2$ and $3\cdot2-3\cdot4/3+8/7=3\frac17$ for $n=3$.

Comment: (+1) This is the way to go. I hope you don't mind that I posted my answer. If you don't think it adds enough, I will remove it.

Comment: @robjohn: The more, the merrier :-) Preferences differ -- to my mind the insight that $\mathbb E(X)=\sum_mP(X\ge m)$ clears things up a lot and avoids what to me feels like unnecessary "clutter" in your solution, but I'm aware that others sometimes find it clearer when things are spelled out closer to how one more naturally thinks about them.

Comment: I've added an asymptotic approximation for the expected value. At least something original :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is the same result gotten by joriki. I have included a bit more detail of the computation (mainly because it is easier for me to follow). I have also added the asymptotic behavior of the expected duration.

---

**Expected Duration**

The probability that after $k$ flips, a particular coin has come up heads, at least once, is $1-\frac1{2^k}$. Thus, the probability that $n$ coins have all come up heads, at least once, is $\left(1-\frac1{2^k}\right)^n$. Therefore, the probability that all coins have come up heads at least once on flip $k$ is $\left(1-\frac1{2^k}\right)^n-\left(1-\frac1{2^{k-1}}\right)^n$. Thus, the expected duration until all coins have come up heads at least once is
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\left[\left(1-\frac1{2^k}\right)^n-\left(1-\frac1{2^{k-1}}\right)^n\right]\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\sum_{k=1}^Nk\left(1-\frac1{2^k}\right)^n-\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}(k+1)\left(1-\frac1{2^k}\right)^n\right]\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[N-\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\left(1-\frac1{2^k}\right)^n\right]\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left[1-\left(1-\frac1{2^k}\right)^n\right]\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j-1}\binom{n}{j}2^{-jk}\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j-1}\binom{n}{j}\frac1{1-2^{-j}}}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Asymptotic Behavior**

As shown above, the expected duration is
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left[1-\left(1-\frac1{2^k}\right)^n\right]\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor}\left[1-e^{-n/2^k}+O\left(\frac1{2^k}\right)\right]
+\sum_{k=\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor+1}^\infty O\left(\frac{n}{2^k}\right)\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\log_2(n)+O(1)}
\end{align}
$$

---

To clarify the estimates above, we have the following.

For $a\gt b$, we have $a^n-b^n\le na^{n-1}(a-b)$, therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
e^{-n/2^k}-\left(1-\frac1{2^k}\right)^n
&\le ne^{-(n-1)/2^k}\left(e^{-1/2^k}-1+\frac1{2^k}\right)\\
&=2^k\left(\frac{n}{2^k}e^{-n/2^k}\right)e^{1/2^k}O\left(\frac1{4^k}\right)\\
&=O\left(\frac1{2^k}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore, since the greatest exponent is $-1$ and they occur with a ratio of $2$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor}e^{-n/2^k}
&\le\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-2^k}\\[6pt]
&\doteq0.521866
\end{align}
$$
Similarly, since $\frac{n}{2^k}\le1$ and the terms occur with a ratio of $2$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor+1}^\infty\frac{n}{2^k}
&\le\sum_{k=0}^\infty2^{-k}\\[6pt]
&=2
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $E(j)$ denote the expected number of additional throws when there are $j$ coins still "alive". It is pretty obvious that the $E(j)$ satisfy 
$$E(0)=0,\qquad E(j)=1+\sum_{k=0}^j{j\choose k}2^{-j}\>E(k)\quad(j\geq1)\ .$$
This leads to the recursion
$$E(j)={1\over 2^j-1}\left(2^j+\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}{j\choose k}E(k)\right)\qquad(j\geq1)$$
and to the values found by @joriki and @JimmyK4542.