# Expected number of days before all magical seeds become apple trees

Tags: probability

This is a question that I came across recently.

At the end of day $0$, $6$ magical seeds are planted. On each day following it, each seed has a chance to magically transform into an apple tree with a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$. The outcomes of seeds are independent of each another.

What is the expected number of days for all six seed to have become apple trees?

My solution:

$E(n)$ - number of expected days from the point that there is only n seed(s) left.
So, $E(1)$ - number of expected days for the last seed to grow.

$E(1) = 1 + \frac{1}{2} E(1) \,or \,E(1) = 2$. This we anyway know from a coin flip analogy.

$E(2) = 1 + \frac{2}{4} E(1) + \frac{1}{4} E(2) \,or\, E(2) = \frac{8}{3}$.
This comes from the fact that if at the end of a day, two seeds are left, I have 3 possible events - i) both seeds become trees the next day ($+1$ day). ii) one seed becomes tree and one seed is left (probability $\frac{2}{4}$). So we further add expected number of days for $E(1)$. iii) None of the seeds become a tree (probability $\frac{1}{4}$). So we add further expected number of days for $E(2)$.

Similarly, $E(3) = 1 + \frac{3}{8} E(1) + \frac{3}{8} E(2) +  \frac{1}{8} E(3)$

$E(4) = 1 + \frac{4}{16} E(1) + \frac{6}{16} E(2) +  \frac{4}{16} E(3) + \frac{1}{16} E(4)$

$E(4) = 1 + \frac{4}{16} E(1) + \frac{6}{16} E(2) +  \frac{4}{16} E(3) + \frac{1}{16} E(4)$

$E(5) = 1 + \frac{5}{32} E(1) + \frac{10}{32} E(2) +  \frac{10}{32} E(3) + \frac{5}{32} E(4) + \frac{1}{32} E(5)$

$E(6) = 1 + \frac{6}{64} E(1) + \frac{15}{64} E(2) +  \frac{20}{64} E(3) + \frac{15}{64} E(4) + \frac{6}{64} E(5) + \frac{1}{64} E(6)$

This gives me an answer of $E(6) = \frac{55160}{13671}$. However the answer given is $(\log_2 6)$. I do not understand how the answer got into $\log$. When I calculate both, they are not same values.

Also, are there more generic and faster methods that I could use to get to the answer?

Comment: I assume that the writer believes something like "I expect half the seeds to turn each round" which is true enough, but not that helpful. With $1$ seed would they expect the answer $\log_2(1)$?  Your analysis is preferable.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X_i$ the time of growth of the $i$th seed, $X$ the time until all grow.
$X_i\sim Geom (0.5)$ so $\Pr(X_i\leq t)=1-0.5^t$ for $t=1,2,\ldots$.
$X$ is the maximum of $X_1,\ldots,X_6$ so $\Pr(X\leq t)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^6\Pr(X_i\leq t)=(1-0.5^t)^6$ and $\Pr(X=t)=\Pr(X\leq t)-\Pr(X\leq t-1)=(1-0.5^t)^6-(1-0.5^{t-1})^6$

Finally, $E(X)=\sum\limits_{t=1}^\infty t\Pr(X=t)=\sum\limits_{t=1}^\infty t\left((1-0.5^t)^6-(1-0.5^{t-1})^6\right)=4.034$ (used [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20t%28%281-0.5%5Et%29%5E6%20-%20%281-0.5%5E%28t-1%29%29%5E6%29%20from%20t%3D1%20to%20infty); I guess there are general methods to compute it) so I guess you are correct and I don't understand the $\log_2(6)$ either.
It could come from an argument like "each day half of the seeds become trees, so we need $\log_2(6)$ days for all to turn trees" but I don't see why this is correct.

Comment: Thank you. I get the same answer.

Comment: Be careful, you are missing a $t$ in the sum giving the esperance.

Comment: @YJT yes you have a typo in the last expression. You need to multiply by $t$.

Comment: Yes. Fixed that. It was just a typo, the formula in Wolfram was correct.

Comment: Yes otherwise you would not have got $4.03$ :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_i$ be the r.v. corresponding to the number of the day where the $i$-th seed become an apple tree. Obviously, for all $i=1, ..., 6$ and for all $n \geq 1$,
$$\mathbb{P}(X_i = n) = \frac{1}{2^n}$$

What you are asked to compute is
$$\mathbb{E}(\max(X_i))$$

But for all integer $n \geq 1$,
$$\mathbb{P}(\max(X_i)=n) = \mathbb{P}(\max(X_i) \leq n) - \mathbb{P}(\max(X_i) \leq n-1) = \prod_{i=1}^6 \mathbb{P}(X_i \leq n) - \prod_{i=1}^6 \mathbb{P}(X_i \leq n-1)$$
$$=\left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^n} \right)^6-\left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \right)^6$$

And $$\mathbb{E}(\max(X_i)) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} n \left[\left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^n} \right)^6-\left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \right)^6\right]$$

Comment: Yes both yours and YJT solution are the same and I think the solution works faster if I am using a computer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be restated as: given the random geometric variables $X_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq 6$, find $$E[\max_i(X_i)]$$

There is in fact no closed form expression, but there are ways to approximate the answer. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26167/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-i-i-d-geometric-random-variables), or Bennett Eisenberg's paper "On the expectation of the maximum of IID geometric random variables" (Statistics and Probability Letters 78 (2008) 135-143). The answer $\log_2(6)$ seems to be an approximation by considering the expectation of the maximum of i.i.d exponentially distributed variables with parameter $\log(2)$ (the exponential distribution is the continuous analogue of the geometric distribution). This expectation is equal to $$\frac{1}{\log(2)}\sum_{k=1}^6 \frac{1}{k}$$The harmonic sum can be (very badly) approximated by $\log(6)$, giving you the approximation you want.

Comment: The approximation $\sum_{k=1}^61/k\approx \log 6$ isn't that bad. The reason the answer is so far out is really that the first approximation ($\text{Geo}(1/2)$ to $\text{Exp}(\log 2)$) is bad.

Comment: $H_6 = 2.45$ while $\log(6) \approx 1.8$. It's not an order of magnitude of difference, but relative to the actual answer it's pretty bad! But I agree, the first approximation is very iffy.

Comment: apologies, I accidentally compared it with $\log_2(6)$! You are quite right.

Comment: ok makes sense but if that is the logic then $E(1)$ needs to be added to it and so the approximation to $4.58$.

Comment: I was doing further search on this and I came across this post. joriki 's answer is interesting https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361569/expected-flips-for-n-coins and so is @robjohn 's asymptotic behavior. It is the same approximation we are talking about.