# Three urns and one coin problem probability distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I have three urns $A$, $B$ and $C$. Urn $A$ contains $M$ balls, urns $B$ and $C$ are empty.

I start drawing balls from $A$, one at a time. For each ball, I toss a coin with probability $p$ of getting *head*: if *tail*, the ball goes in $B$, if *head* it goes in $C$.

Once  $A$ is empty, I take the balls in $B$ and put them back in $A$, and I start the process again. This is repeated $n$ times, until all balls are in $C$.

Is it possible to define $P(n \leq N)$ analytically for any $M$, $N$ and $p$?

I thought I could start from a binomial, so I can calculate the probability of having $k$ balls in $C$ at the end of the first run, but then I am stuck.

Sorry for any imprecision in my language.

Comment: Re your question 1, you haven’t fully formulated any problem to even assign a name to.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum you are right, I edited question 1 out.

Comment: Note:  this is the equivalent to saying "you flip  $n$ coins repeatedly, discarding all the heads and re-flipping the tails.  What's the probability that you have discarded all the coins in $N$ turns or fewer?"  In turn, that is equivalent to asking "what's the distribution of the maximal stopping time when you flip $n$ coins (and stop each coin when you get an $H$)?".

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361569/expected-flips-for-n-coins/1361582#1361582) is an equivalent problem, which only computes the expected value.  The same technique apply (indeed, it's likely that they first solve for the distribution, but I didn't study the responses to confirm that).